# Error push, repository not authorized on GitHub

Tags: github, repository

I am trying to push the changes on the repository of a project, but when i try to push the changes, it says:

```
Git command returned with the following error:
https://alejandromgz@github.com/davfer28/prueba.git: not authorized
```

How can i solve this problem? I tried creating a test project and it says the same exact problem, and it doesn't ask me for an api or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your OS and git configuration. Check if you have a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** that might have cached wrong credentials (username/password)

```
git config -l|grep credential
```

On Windows, for instance, open the [Microsoft Credential Manager](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/).